# How to revert rm -rf in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, rm

I was trying to run a set of commands (all starting with `rm -rf`) to completely remove an application in Mac OS X. All my folders in Desktop are accidentally removed somehow. Is there a way to bring them back?

Comment: Do you have a backup? If not, and the files are important, I'd shut the computer down immediately to minimize the chances of overwriting whatever's left. Then research data recovery options from another computer.

Comment: I have partial backup. Any recovery application suggestions? Disk Drill sees nothing except junk files.

Comment: Time Machine in use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) but keep your expectations low, it's pretty unlikely that you would get back your data after an `rm -rf` operation. You can use[brew](https://brew.sh/) to install PhotoRec, it's part of *testdisk* (`brew install testdisk`).

If the files lost were on your Desktop, you may want to check on iCloud. By default [Desktop and Documents files sync to iCloud Drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985) and most people don't deactivate that setting.